# animate() for view is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, animation

I wanted to create an effect like this : 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTVIK.png)

The bottom left circle is going to be moved to the circle at top right.

I tried to implement it by :

1 - Getting the coordinates of the top right circle by :
(I tried these two)
The first method :

```
relativeLayout_1_x = (int)relativeLayout_1_2.getX() ;
    relativeLayout_1_y = (int)relativeLayout_1_2.getY();
    relativeLayout_2_x = (int)relativeLayout_2_2.getX();
    relativeLayout_2_y = (int)relativeLayout_2_2.getY();
```

The second method :

```
    int[] _pos_a = new int[2];
    int[] _pos_b = new int[2];

    relativeLayout_1_2.getLocationInWindow(_pos_a);
    relativeLayout_2_2.getLocationInWindow(_pos_b);

    relativeLayout_1_x = _pos_a[0];
    relativeLayout_1_y =  _pos_a[1];

    relativeLayout_2_x =  _pos_b[0];
    relativeLayout_2_y =  _pos_b[1];
```

2 - Animating the relativeLayout to move to the position by :

```
button_1.animate()
        .translationX((float)relativeLayout_1_x)
        .translationY((float)relativeLayout_1_y);
```

But instead of moving to the position , The view goes down :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGu03.png)

Instead of using "translationX I tried using ".x" but to no avail.

I don't know what's my error. All the four circles are in a RelativeLayout which is in a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

For the first I suppose you animate View to incorrect value.

change it to

```
button_1.animate()
        .translationX((float)relativeLayout_2_x)
        .translationY((float)relativeLayout_2_y);
```